# What is the simplest way to refine a list's contents (words) based on character frequency and position? (C#)

Tags: c#, list

I'm writing a console-environment Hangman game for my introductory programming class. The player chooses the word length and number of guesses they would like. 'Easy mode' is simple enough... generate a random number to use as the list's index and check that the chosen word is the right length. However, 'hard mode' requires the list to be refined as the game progresses, choosing the largest list of possibilities given the letters guessed.

I should note, we are not using the C# List class but instead, creating array-based structs:

```
    struct ListType
    {
        public type[] items;
        public int count;
    }

    //defined as:

    ListType myList = new ListType();
    myList.items = new type[max value];
    myList.count = 0;
```

Anyway, here's an example of the way 'hard mode' should go:

```
Word List:
hole
airplane
lame
photos
cart
mole

(player chooses word length of 4)

Word List (refined):
hole
lame
cart
mole

(player guesses "l", then "e")

Word List (refined):
hole
mole
```

"Lame" is omitted because more words have the "...le..." pattern. The technique that makes sense to me (but isn't working the way I'd like) is storing each word's pattern to an array (ie: "mole" and "hole" = 0011, and "lame" = 1001), and counting up the duplicates to determine the larger list.

Is this the way I should be doing it? I'm new to programming and have just under a year's worth of experience, so I guess answer as such.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? Because LINQ will greatly help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses everyone! I've saved a backup and scratched the chooseWord method completely. Going to re-create it using the advice in these answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of approaching this. A simple way would be to keep track of a list for all candidate words and calculate the amount of matching sequences for that word as well as log the best matching sequence. This way you can both sort on the best sequence and the amount of sequences when the best sequence alone is not a good enough measurement tool. I hope it becomes obvious how to modify this code in order to only sort on the best sequence.

Firstly i setup a test case like:

```
// mimic the scenario given by the QA
string[] wordList = new string[] { "hole", "airplane", "lame", "photos", "cart", "mole" };
int wordLength = 4;
List<char> requiredCharacters = new List<char>{ 'l', 'e'};
```

After which i filter the wordList and calculate the best matches which i finally group together to produce the desired result:

```
// filter all words that dont match the required length
var candidateWords = wordList.Where(x => x.Length == wordLength);

// define a result set holding all the words and all their matches
Dictionary<string, List<int>> refinedWordSet = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

foreach (string word in candidateWords)
{
    List<int> matches = new List<int>() { 0 };

    int currentMatchCount = 0;
    foreach (char character in word)
    {
        if (requiredCharacters.Contains(character))
        {
            currentMatchCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            // if there were previous matches
            if (currentMatchCount > 0)
            {
                // save the current match
                matches.Add(currentMatchCount);
                currentMatchCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // if there was a match at the end
    if (currentMatchCount > 0)
    {
        // save the last match
        matches.Add(currentMatchCount);
    }

    refinedWordSet.Add(word, matches);
}   

// sort by a combination of the total amount of matches as well as the highest match
var goupedRefinedWords = from entry in refinedWordSet
                            group entry.Key by new { Max = entry.Value.Max(), Total = entry.Value.Sum() } into grouped
                            select grouped;

foreach (var entry in goupedRefinedWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Word list with best match: {0} and total match {1}: {2}", 
        entry.Key.Max,
        entry.Key.Total,
        entry.Aggregate("", (result, nextWord) => result += nextWord + ", "));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Pay attention to the comments in the code

Answer (score 0):

So you look through the array for strings that match the guess pattern.

In the specific case of "le" you culd simply use `String.IndexOf()`.  If you require a more cmplex pattern.. say "*le?" (where * and ? follow DOS-like wildcard pattern) you could employ a dynamicly-cnstructed regex pattern (easy, but performace-heavy if used in a near-realtime system), or character scanning (read each char from the screen and match to your pattern) (more difficult, harder to maintain, better performance for a small number of elements in a near-RT system).

As this is homework, I wouldn't worry about performace profiling at all right now.

Also, that struct looks mighty goofy.  There are certainly better constructs for this type of thing.  Like a `List<String>`, or just a `String[]`... both of which have a `.Count` property.